# How to deal with columns that should be presents in the calculations in the transformers and should not be in the training data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, error-handling, class-transformer

I created two custom transformers and i used a ColumnTransformer to group them and then used them in pipeline but the columns used for the claculations in my tranformers should not be in the training data

```
custom_transformers = ColumnTransformer([
('probability_estimator', ProbabilityEstimator(), ['softbin_first_test', 'time_window', 'total_pass', 'total_fail']),
('contact_site_estimator', ContactSiteEstimator(), ['tester_id', 'site_number', 'short_window']),
('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(), ['softbin_first_test', 'bincode_type_last_retest'])])
```

Here is my Pipeline:

```
# Define the classifier
classifier = LogisticRegression()

# Create the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
('custom_transformers', custom_transformers),
('classifier', classifier)
])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

Comment: I don't see how your goal (in the title question) relates to the error.  I have some ideas towards the goal, but some of them would rely on modifying your custom transformers, so providing (even some dummified version of) them would be helpful.  As to the error message, always provide the complete traceback, and ideally some toy version of your data.

Comment: Which of the listed columns do you want not to end up reaching the model?

Comment: I want just ''softbin_first_test' and the new columns that will provide the transformers in the training